# Is O(1) considered polynomial time?

Tags: np-complete, asymptotics, big-o-notation, hamiltonian-path

I am reading about P and NP and looking at the reduction of a Rudrata/Hamiltonian path to a Rudrata cycle. I think adding an extra node and 2 edges connecting the start, `s` and the target, `t` is `O(1)` time as this doesn't depend on the size of the graph. *Algorithms* by Dasgupta et al. says that the pre and post processing steps take polynomial time.

> One last detail, crucial but typically easy to check, is that the pre- and postprocessing functions take time polynomial in the size of the instance
> *(G, s, t)*.

This makes me think that `O(1)` is polynomial time. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any constant is a [polynomial of degree zero](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial).

Comment: Are the pre and processing times also $O(1)$?

Comment: I think you need to explicitly define these steps, possibly in a different question.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/136915/is-reduction-from-rudrata-hamiltonian-path-to-rudrata-hamiltonian-cycle-o1